# can I use a wirebrush to clean brass drop ear?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have a small leak when I try to attach shower arm to the drop ear. The drop ear is a brass NPT fitting. Few things I can try to fix the leak, pipe dope, different shower arm, replace drop ear (last resort), but when I inspect the drop ear it looks like it could use a good cleaning to begin with. Can I clean the drop ear threads with a wire brush? Or would it damage the threads?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tp6f.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Comment: The wire brush should be the same or softer material for cleaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually looks pretty clean.

I use [thread sealer](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/solvents-and-cements/plumbers-putty-and-sealers/4396321?store=15404&gclid=Cj0KCQjwrfymBhCTARIsADXTablKM9n_4PcUD8eiGP_kr39Fq_5AwwH5OOqlzhujkCZ6NC_m00kCSRUaAnpuEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) rather than teflon tape.

I rarely have leaks after installing the shower arm.

Comment: Some of the threads in the last pic look a bit beat up.

Comment: That's actually *the one place* I do use tape instead of pipe dope. You vary the number of wraps it takes to stay in between, not leaking, and ending up pointing down, once it's tight enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another thread sealing technique is to use fibers along with the pipe dope. In Europe and British commonwealth countries "plumber's hemp" fiber is used. This is available in the US but I don't see why a coarse, strong sewing thread would not also work.

The way I envision this being applied would be to very lightly coat the male threads with pipe dope, then wind thread CW into the grooves (so that as the threads are engaged the thread is tightened not unwound), then put more dope on top of the threads before screwing it in.

https://youtu.be/bFXgwO9qszY but the use of the hacksaw blade to cut the excess hemp seems very wrong to me. Just snip with scissors or a utility knife.

This video has good info but the presenter somewhat eccentric. https://youtu.be/Y7LW8F1wZAY

In some countries other than the USA parallel threads are sometimes used for water pipe threaded connections rather than the tapered threads used in the US. Water pipe connections with parallel threads must have fiber used to make a leak free joint.